# Combine like Information

Tags: sql

This query return the following results from two tables. The count is the number of products associated with an ID:

```
select pog.DBKey
      ,Count(pos.DBParentProductKey)
as Total
from ix_spc_planogram as pog with (nolock)
   , ix_spc_position as pos with (nolock)
where pog.dbkey = pos.dbparentplanogramkey
and pog.Value4 = 358
group by pog.dbkey
```

```
DBKEY  Total
2134   20
2132   22
2133   20
```

Now I need to use this information to determine if 2134 has the same DBParentProductKeys as 2133. I need to group all like DbKEys together like the following

```
DBKEY    Assortment
2134     1                1+1 because it has the same ParentProductKeys
2133     1
2132     2
```

Any ideas of how to solve this problem would be very helpful.

Comment: Do you mean the same `COUNT()` of `DBParentProductKeys`, or identical `DBParentProductKeys`?  If the second, why not simply output and use those?  Oh, and the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause) is considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: Friendly design advice: the "ix_" object name prefix typically denotes a table index.  Try naming the tables something like "tbl_planogram."

Comment: @Norla - I'd avoid prefixing my objects with type information.  What happens if the DBAs restructure the database, so there's now a **view** presenting the equivalent information?

Comment: @X-Zero I'll try to avoid a lengthy discussion in a question thread, suffice it to say that I'd be hard-pressed to find a scenario in which that would present a problem.  I'd be happy to continue this on chat.  : )